# Can BufferedReader continue to read line in text file when pass to another function?

Tags: java, function, loops, bufferedreader

I have this function to read text file with BufferedReader. I want to know if I can called another function and pass the readline/continue to read text file. If it can pass, can it loop the same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BufferedReader` object is self-contained (thanks to Java's heavy emphasis on [Object Orientation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)), so you are free to pass it between functions and inside loops, and it will retain it's state - including the read line.

However, if you are trying to call a method to process the line you have just read, then it would be much more efficient to pass the line itself to the method as a `String`, instead of passing the entire BufferedReader object.

```
while( myBufferedReader.ready() ) {
    String line = myBufferedReader.readLine();
    processLine( line );
}
```