# Is it wise to put BufferedReader in another function that is use for retrieving data from input file

Tags: java

I am learning how to factor my codes so I thought it would be nice to create a function solely for retrieving a char from the input file. This is what I have in mind:

```
    public char getChar( String infile )
    {
       try
       {
           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( infile ));
           int ch = in.read();
           // do some decision making
           return (char)ch;
       }
       catch( IOException e )
       {
           System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
           System.exit(1);
       } 
     }
```

Then in the constructor or some another function I can use it like this:

```
    public constructor( String infile )
    {
        char newChar = getChar( infile ); 
        // some lines of codes later.. need another character
        newChar = getChar( infile );
    }
```

P.S. I haven't test these codes so it might contain so errors, but i hope my idea is understandable. 
Please tell me if this is a good/bad idea or this kind of factoring can be done in different ways. Thank you for reading.

EDIT: Yes, I do want the BufferedReader to get the next char in line.. and not start over

 Ex: infile contains a String like this: "ABC" 
 thisShouldBeA = getChar( infile ); 
thisSoundBeB = getChar( inflie );

Comment: You create a new reader every time you call `getChar`. If you want to get the _next_ char, you need to keep the reader open and re-use it in every call. Could you clarify what exactly your question is?

Comment: @C-Otto: thank you! I just edited my question. I do want to get the _next_ char (the one next in line in the infile if that makes sense..)

Comment: You need to retain some state between call otherwise getChar would only ever read the first character.  BTW It doesn't sound like a good idea to me.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I read this Post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629269/can-bufferedreader-continue-to-read-line-in-text-file-when-pass-to-another-funct) so I thought this method is possible..

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Hello! because I need to check some conditions before deciding if i should get a new char from infile or use another one. Sorry I didn't post my whole program.. i don't have the file with me at the moment.. And I just thought factoring my codes would look nicer! Thanks!

Comment: You could create an object which wraps the file name and can give you the nest character each time.  Note: you have to remember to close each file when you have finished with them ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Helper {
  private BufferedReader in;

  Helper(String infile) {
    this.in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infile));
  }

  char getChar() {
    try {
      return in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
       System.exit(1);
    }
  }

  void close() {
    this.in.close();
  }
}

class Other {
  void something(String infile) {
    Helper helper = new Helper(infile);
    char newChar = helper.getChar();
    char anotherNewChar = helper.getChar();

    helper.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Everything else hurts my eyes :)

Comment: Frankly, I don't really see what you gain with such a wrapper. Using a BufferedReader directly is as easy. And your exception handling is a bit radical. Moreover, your Helper doesn't implement Closable, which prevents using the try-with-resources construct.

Comment: I delivered what the OP asked for, including his exception handler.

Comment: @C-Otto: Thank you for your answer! I've never used a wrapper class before but this looks promising :) Thanks again!

Comment: ... I would add that what the OP asked for is suspect so it's not surprising the solution is going to have difficulties.

Comment: @C-Otto: Just one more question.. so this is not True? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629269/can-bufferedreader-continue-to-read-line-in-text-file-when-pass-to-another-funct)
The Answer says "A BufferedReader object is self-contained (thanks to Java's heavy emphasis on Object Orientation), so you are free to pass it between functions and inside loops, and it will retain it's state - including the read line." Thank you!

Comment: The comment is correct. In order to make it work as you wish, you need to re-use the very same object all the time. Your code in the question always creates a new object, which is problematic.